# Yielding in Rails partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-4.2, partials

I'm using Rails 4.2, but following along with the Rails 5.0 documentation on partials, trying to build a search partial. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

I am getting the Search button, so the shared partial is rendering, however, it does not seem to be yielding back to the calling block.  I'm not getting the label or the search_field.  Did I do something dumb, or does this not function in Rails 4.2?  Seems like this should just be basic Ruby.

I did notice that this example is not included in the docs for 4.2. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

shared/_search_filters.html.erb

```
<div class="search">
  <%= search_form_for @q, html: { class: 'form-inline'} do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= yield f %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit 'Search', class: 'btn btn-default', role: 'button' %>
  <% end %>
</div> <!-- /.search -->
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= render 'shared/search_filters', search: @q do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :search, 'Search (optional)', class: 'control-label'  %>
  <%= f.search_field :name_or_description_cont,
                     class: 'form-control',
                     placeholder: 'Search (optional)' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Your render is working - you see the button. Both rails 4.2 and 5.0 guides use <%= yield f %>. I think the issue is with this section "  <%= search_form_for @q, html: { class: 'form-inline'} do |f| %>" Are you using ransack? Is that why you aren't using form_for and are using search_form_for?

Comment: yes, we're using ransack.  Anything I add inside the form-group renders on the page, but the yield does not function

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Rails only supports yielding to blocks in partials if you're using 5.0 or later.  From the [release notes for 5.0](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/5_0_release_notes.html#action-view-notable-changes):

> Allow blocks while rendering with the `render partial:` helper.

Comment: In Rails 7, `render partial: "my_partial", ... do` is actually not working. You need to use `render "my_partial", ... do` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try replace this at your index:

```
 render layout: 'shared/search_filters', locals: { search: @q } do |f|
```

Comment: Thanks Pedro.  Unfortunately I left that project a few months back, so I can't see what my solution to this problem actually was. :)

But maybe this will help someone else.